# Using SQL Server Dynamic Management Views, how can I get a Stored Proc Parameter's Default Value?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Say I've got some throw-away sample procedure that looks like this:

```
CREATE procedure simpletestproc_prc    
(     
  @companyId int,     
  @objectid float = 5.678,     
  @personname varchar(255)  = 'hello world'  
) as        

select @companyId + 10, @objectid, @personname
```

I can use the below query to get the types and names of all the parameters:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM sys.procedures sp
INNER JOIN sys.parameters parm 
    ON sp.object_id = parm.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.types typ 
    ON parm.system_type_id = typ.system_type_id
WHERE sp.name = 'simpletestproc_prc'
order by parameter_id
```

But none of those columns (even parm.default_value) has 5.678 or 'hello world'.  How can I retrieve those values?  If it matters, you can assume either SQL Server 2005 or 2008.

Comment: Just comment that Dynamic Management Views are the ones that start with dm_ and they are called 'dynamic' because the they are not backed up by storage, but created dynamically from runtime code when interrogated. The views you refer to are called Catalog Views, or Metadata Views, and are views on top of real storage, tables in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dev.mainsoft.com/Default.aspx?tabid=181

Basically, you read sys.comments (where the text of the stored procedure are stored)

Comment: Something dm views *can't do*?! /weep  At least they gave me code to do the ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function I use.   It is quick and dirty, but works:

```
create function dbo.paramDefault(@ProcName VARCHAR(128),@paramName VARCHAR(64) )
returns varchar(128)
as
begin
    DECLARE @theId  INT
    DECLARE @ans    VARCHAR(128)
    DECLARE @theLine VARCHAR(2000)
    DECLARE @x      INT

    SET @theID = object_id(@procName)
    if @theID is NULL
        RETURN @ans

    SET @theLine = Object_definition (@theID)       
    SET @theLine = substring(@theLine,charIndex(@ProcName,@theLine)+len(@procName),999)
    SET @theLine = rtrim(ltrim(left(@theLine,charIndex(') as',@theLine)-1)))+','

    SET @x = charindex(@paramName,@theLine)
    IF @x > 0 
    BEGIN
        SET @theLine = rtrim(SUBSTRING(@theLine,@x,999))
        SET @x      = charindex(',',@theLine)
        SET @theLine = left(@theLine,@x-1)
        SET @x      = charIndex('=',@theLine)
        if @x > 0   SET @ans = rtrim(subString(@theLine,@x+1,999))
    END 

    RETURN @ans
end

GO
select dbo.paramDefault('simpletestProc_prc','personName')
select dbo.paramDefault('simpletestProc_prc','objectID')
select dbo.paramDefault('simpletestProc_prc','companyId')
```